# State dropdown empty on form with Drupal webform integration

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, addresses

We are running Civi 4.7.29. with Drupal.  We have a webform using Drupal webform integration which populates civicrm fields.

we noticed that the state drop down was empty when previously it was working correctly.

Has anyone come accross this issue?

I checked the state province table in civicrm and it is not empty.

Thanks
[image]

Yes there is an error on the page.  Please see below.  How do I fix this please?
[image]

Comment: can you add some screenshots?

Comment: yes screenshots please!

Comment: Select list in Webform CiviCRM could have a setting which is called live/static. If static is selected you can enter the possible staes yourself. Also a state could be selected after a country is selected.

Comment: @JaapJansma I don't think webform-civicrm will allow that field to be static as it is an ajax field. Vish can you please open your browser console (F12) refresh the page and then see if any error messages appear?

Comment: `webformProp()` definitely **is** a function in all versions of Webform 4 that I'm aware of. What version of Webform and Webform-CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: Hi Coleman.  we are using Webform Version: 7.x-4.16 and Webform CiviCRM Version: 7.x-4.20. I believe this is the latest version?

Comment: Our developer updated the jQuery version and there are no javascript errors anymore on the page.  However the address fields (street, postal code, Country, State etc) are not being saved in Civi.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

Usually when a javascript element fails to work on your page, it's caused by a general javascript failure on your website. This can be caused by incompatible plugins or themes, etc. So the problem may have nothing to do with the state/province field or webform-civicrm; if Javascript has crashed, then it can't run. To narrow down the problem, open up the console in your webbrowser (F12) and look for any error messages. If the error message contains the name of a plugin, try disabling it. Or take a screenshot of the error and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Our developer updated the jQuery version and this seemes to have solved the javascript errors on the page.